# Using Custom Gestures in XAML Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I'm working on Xamarin forms application where I want to have some gestures on some of the labels like long press, left and right swipe gesture etc.. But Xamarin Forms does not support these gestures yet. So I have created Custom render class each for android and iOS refering [this](http://arteksoftware.com/gesture-recognizers-with-xamarin-forms/)

Now the problem is that I want to bind the gesture event as Command in ViewModel from Xaml file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following repository. It will solve your problem.

https://github.com/chrispy2day/Xamarin-Gestures-Demo

The repository link includes all the Swipe up, down, left and right gesture with the custom rendering and *MVVM* pattern.